# Need node.js for Reveal.js to read external markdown file?

Tags: reveal.js

Can Reveal.js read from an external markdown file without requiring node.js? Or will embedded markdown (in the html) work without node.js. In other words, I need to use Apache and can't accommodate node.js.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will work without node.js, but you will need some type of web server if you're previewing it on localhost (i.e. directly viewing the file won't work). I use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the working directory for testing things locally.